# PHP Doctrine frustration: loading models doesn't work..?

Tags: php, codeigniter, doctrine

I'm almost losing it, i really hope someone can help me out!

I'm using Doctrine with CodeIgniter. Everything is setup correctly and works until I generate the classes and view the website.

> Fatal error: Class 'BaseObjecten' not found in /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/application/models/Objecten.php on line 13

I'm using the following bootstrapper (as CodeIgniter plugin):

```
<?php
// system/application/plugins/doctrine_pi.php

// load Doctrine library
require_once BASEPATH . '/plugins/Doctrine/lib/Doctrine.php';

// load database configuration from CodeIgniter
require_once APPPATH.'/config/database.php';

// this will allow Doctrine to load Model classes automatically
spl_autoload_register(array('Doctrine', 'autoload'));

// we load our database connections into Doctrine_Manager
// this loop allows us to use multiple connections later on
foreach ($db as $connection_name => $db_values) {

    // first we must convert to dsn format
    $dsn = $db[$connection_name]['dbdriver'] .
        '://' . $db[$connection_name]['username'] .
        ':' . $db[$connection_name]['password'].
        '@' . $db[$connection_name]['hostname'] .
        '/' . $db[$connection_name]['database'];

    Doctrine_Manager::connection($dsn,$connection_name);
}

// CodeIgniter's Model class needs to be loaded
require_once BASEPATH.'/libraries/Model.php';

// telling Doctrine where our models are located
Doctrine::loadModels(APPPATH.'/models');

// (OPTIONAL) CONFIGURATION BELOW

// this will allow us to use "mutators"
Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->setAttribute(
    Doctrine::ATTR_AUTO_ACCESSOR_OVERRIDE, true);

// this sets all table columns to notnull and unsigned (for ints) by default
Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->setAttribute(
    Doctrine::ATTR_DEFAULT_COLUMN_OPTIONS,
    array('notnull' => true, 'unsigned' => true));

// set the default primary key to be named 'id', integer, 4 bytes
Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->setAttribute(
    Doctrine::ATTR_DEFAULT_IDENTIFIER_OPTIONS,
    array('name' => 'id', 'type' => 'integer', 'length' => 4));
?>
```

## Anyone?

p.s. I also tried adding the following right after // (OPTIONAL CONFIGURATION)

```
Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->setAttribute(Doctrine::ATTR_MODEL_LOADING, Doctrine::MODEL_LOADING_CONSERVATIVE);
spl_autoload_register(array('Doctrine', 'modelsAutoload'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tried?

```
<?php

spl_autoload_register(array('Doctrine', 'autoload'));
spl_autoload_register(array('Doctrine', 'modelsAutoload'));
$manager = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance();

$manager->setAttribute(Doctrine::ATTR_MODEL_LOADING, Doctrine::MODEL_LOADING_CONSERVATIVE);
$manager->setAttribute(Doctrine::ATTR_AUTOLOAD_TABLE_CLASSES, true);
$manager->setAttribute(Doctrine_Core::ATTR_AUTOLOAD_TABLE_CLASSES, true);
Doctrine::loadModels(APPPATH.'models');
```

Also, depending on your server platform, you might want to check out using xdebug and a IDE that supports live breakpoints.  That combination allows you to track down most autoloader issues relatively quickly by setting a breakpoint on the first line of the classdef that has a dependency issue.

Comment: I found myself digging in Core.php. But you're right.. It was related to the position of the loadModels() function.

Comment: @ropstah  One more suggestion for working with Doctrine in Code Igniter... unless you're accessing a Doctrine_ prefixed class, try to use Doctrine::getTable("SubjectMatter") to get SubjectMatterTable.php.  It minimizes confusion if someone else is reading your code in trying to figure out what you're using.

Answer (score 2):

Just a small hack

Add this line

`Doctrine::loadModels(APPPATH.'/models/generated');`

before ...

`Doctrine::loadModels(APPPATH.'/models');`

or other path where you think your autoGenerated BaseClasses are in 
application/helper/doctrine_pi.php