# Problem with Codeigniter and Doctrine, migrating from Windows to Linux server

Tags: php, codeigniter, migration, doctrine

I’ve recently been learning how to use both Doctrine and CI and have been overhauling my website using both tools… all has been absolutely awesome up until the following issue(s) occurred:

Essentially it would seem that either PHP, CI or Doctrine can’t find my Base classes unless I explicitly require/include them in the corresponding model’s class?

> EG: Fatal error: Class ‘BaseServiceCatagory’ not found

My live site is sitting on a Linux box with PHP 5.2.6 and my dev site is on Windows with PHP 5.2.9-1. It works perfectly fine on Windows but the live site continually gives me the error posted above.

I’m hoping that someone here might have had similar problem before and might have some suggestions regarding what might be the cause.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the solution here: http://www.misty-stix.com/codeigniter-doctrine-migration-from-windows-to-linux/

Answer (score 0):

Based on the naming convention I'm going to assume that's a Doctrine class. What does your Doctrine setup/bootstrap setup look?  My first guess would be you're pointing to a Windows style file path when you tell Doctrine where to load its models from.

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply. i installed doctrine as a plugin to the system. i created a doctrine_pi.php file and is located in the system\application\plugins directory.

Comment: the contents of the doctrine_pi.php file can be found here: http://pastebin.com/UxjkFfs6

Comment: Add some debugging code to Doctrine::autoload and try to determine why your class files aren't being included on the server.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and the answer to this question fixed it for me: 
[PHP Doctrine frustration: loading models doesn't work..?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546391/php-doctrine-frustration-loading-models-doesnt-work)